# Get access to local variables from Main() method

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner in C#. And so far I know a  `public static` variables can be accessed by any other class and local variables inside a `public static` method is not accessible by other class. So,In this case I want to get access to all the keys from `Main()` method and do something with them. How can I do that? There has to be a way.  I thought of using `return`  but it will return only one key value the one I will choose. Is there any way to return more then one value at a time?

This is the code that generate keys

```
class keyCreation
{
    public static void Key_Derivation_Function(byte[] password)
    {
        string salt = "12345678";
        byte[] saltbyte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt);
        Console.WriteLine("Password length: " + password.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Saltbyte lenght: " + saltbyte.Length);
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes keyGenerate = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, saltbyte, 1000);
        byte[] key1 = keyGenerate.GetBytes(16);
        byte[] key2 = keyGenerate.GetBytes(32);
        byte[] key3 = keyGenerate.GetBytes(16);
        byte[] key4 = keyGenerate.GetBytes(32);
        byte[] key5 = keyGenerate.GetBytes(16);
        byte[] key6 = keyGenerate.GetBytes(16);
        byte[] key7 = keyGenerate.GetBytes(32);
    }
}
```

And this is the main method,

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)

    {

        //user giving input
        Console.WriteLine("Plaintext:  ");
        string plaintext = Console.ReadLine();
        byte[] text = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plaintext);
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Password: ");
        string pass = Console.ReadLine();
        byte[] password = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pass);
        keyCreation.Key_Derivation_Function(password); 
        // get the keys and do something with the keys

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As example you can return the same class, that contains static method:

```
public class keyCreation
{
    public byte[] Key1;
    public byte[] Key2;
    public byte[] Key3;
    public byte[] Key4;
    public byte[] Key5;
    public byte[] Key6;
    public byte[] Key7;

    public static keyCreation Key_Derivation_Function(byte[] password)
    {
        string salt = "12345678";
        byte[] saltbyte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt);
        Console.WriteLine("Password length: " + password.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Saltbyte lenght: " + saltbyte.Length);
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes keyGenerate = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, saltbyte, 1000);
        return new keyCreation()
        {
            Key1 = keyGenerate.GetBytes(16),
            Key2 = keyGenerate.GetBytes(32),
            Key3 = keyGenerate.GetBytes(16),
            Key4 = keyGenerate.GetBytes(32),
            Key5 = keyGenerate.GetBytes(16),
            Key6 = keyGenerate.GetBytes(16),
            Key7 = keyGenerate.GetBytes(32)
        };
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //user giving input
        Console.WriteLine("Plaintext:  ");
        string plaintext = Console.ReadLine();
        byte[] text = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plaintext);
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Password: ");
        string pass = Console.ReadLine();
        byte[] password = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pass);
        var result = keyCreation.Key_Derivation_Function(password);
        // get the keys and do something with the keys        
        var key1 = result.Key1;
        var key2 = result.Key2;
        ...
    }
}
```

In this case the class keyCreation contains all KeyN field and return its instance from Key_Derivation_Function method.

Another way is out/ref params:

```
public class keyCreation
{
    public static void Key_Derivation_Function(byte[] password, out byte[] key1, out byte[] key2, ...)
    {
        string salt = "12345678";
        byte[] saltbyte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt);
        Console.WriteLine("Password length: " + password.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Saltbyte lenght: " + saltbyte.Length);
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes keyGenerate = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, saltbyte, 1000);
        key1 = keyGenerate.GetBytes(16);
        key2 = keyGenerate.GetBytes(32);
        ...
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ...
        byte[] key1, key2, ...;
        keyCreation.Key_Derivation_Function(password, out key1, out key2, ...);
        ...
    }
}
```

Also you can return tuples, arrays of arrays, etc.

Comment: so, the return type is a method! wow never seen this type of coding before. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make the function return all keys. Maybe as an array of keys (`byte[][]`). Or, if you don't like the double-array define yourself a wrapper class:

```
class Key { public byte[] Bytes; }
```

and return a `Key[]`.

Don't overuse static variables. They make the program confusing because it is hard to track when they are written and when read.